# Presto function at_timezone results in incorrect UTC time for timezone 'Africa/Cairo'

Tags: presto

I need to rely on the Presto function at_timezone to return the correct UTC time offset for a given timezone. The function currently returns an incorrect UTC time, and hence offset value, for the timezone 'Africa/Cairo'
The statement:

SELECT
DATE_DIFF(
'minute',
CAST(at_timezone(CAST('2023-09-30 12:00:00.000 Africa/Cairo' as timestamp with time zone), 'UTC') AS timestamp),
CAST('2023-09-30 12:00:00.000' as timestamp)
)

returns 120 (minutes) - the correct value is 180.
How to you go about getting something like this corrected?

Have searched for some Presto contact point but to no avail.

Comment: I don't have an answer as to what's broken in Presto, but this works fine in the latest version of Trino, a fork of Presto: https://trino.io

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Cairo just reintroduced DST starting April 28, 2023: https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/dst-egypt-2023.html
And Presto hasn't applied this yet.

The best approach is to open an issue on https://github.com/prestodb/presto to trace this change.

Update:

New tzdata is updated in this PR: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/pull/21329
The fix is included in the 0.285 release. It fixes the Cairo timezone issue you mentioned here.